# Switching circuit using a MOSFET to not destroy the power supply

Tags: power-supply, mosfet

I am designing a temperature control system with arduino and PID , and i am using a Mosfet to switch the PwM from the arduino and allow 2A 5V heater to heat up.
[image]

Can you tell me a good switching circuit, i can use in additional with the MOSFET , since i assume that the switching will destroy the Power supply on the Heater. because to the temperature is oscillating between (37deg and 36 deg) so the Mosfet keeps putting in betweeen On and Off.

The Pwm is oscillating between 0 and 255 no (in  betweens)

Thanks

Comment: 1. You're showing a BJT, not a MOSFET.  2. A heater can typically be PWM'd without damage, but you reference a power supply so you have to give us a link to the datasheet or more information about the heater.  3.  Why choose a motor to represent the heater??

Comment: Your schematic shows Arduino pins 7 and 8 shorted together.

Comment: This isn't a proper schematic, go find some examples of projects where something is switched on/off using a MOSFET. That saves you from "guessing" like you're doing here which also shows that you didn't do proper research first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because controlling a heater isn't new, it has been done many times before and plenty of projects can be found that show you how to do this. Instead you just "guessed" and you made some errors which is to be expected. These could have been avoided if you simply had done some research first.

Comment: what leads you to believe that the power supply would be destroyed?

Comment: I have edited my post thank you for informing me about my errors.

Comment: @jsotola I think it is because the MOSFET is switching on and OFF so much i suppose it is not healthy for the power supply to send current on and off ofcaurse that;s my question also .